# Testing: How to emulate netbook resolution?

Tags: windows, testing

I want my app to look good on devices with low resolutions (e.g. 640 x 480). Does anyone know of a way to emulate such resolutions on Windows (e.g. in VMWare) ?
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of app? Windows? Web?